# How can I count the number of documents grouping by nested Array?

Tags: mongodb

I have some documents like :

```
{
    "product" : [{
        "name" : "apple",
        "seller" : [
            {
                "name" : "Alice",
                "gender" : 1
            },
            {
                "name" : "Bob",
                "gender" : 0
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "name" : "anotherApple",
        "seller" : [
            {
                "name" : "Bob",
                "gender" : 0
            }
        ]
    }],
    "date" : "someDay"
},
{
    "product" : [{
        "name" : "apple",
        "seller" : [
            {
                "name" : "Alice",
                "gender" : 1
            },
            {
                "name" : "CName",
                "gender" : 0
            }
        ]
    }],
    "date" : "someDay"
}
```

And I wanna count the number of one seller's bills, in this case , which is supposed to be :

```
{
    "Alice" : 2,
    "Bob" : 1,
    "CName" : 1
}
```

I have tried some ways such like unwind `seller` in `product` but none of them works. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't understand, Bob occurs two times, why don't you count it as 2 ?

Comment: Because the result should be the number of documents, while 2 is the number of products. @Omar Abbas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `addToSet` to have a list of ids.
And count them with `$size`in a project

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$unwind": "$product"
},
{
  "$unwind": "$product.seller"
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$product.seller.name",
    list_ids: {
      "$addToSet": "$_id"
    }
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    "_id": 1,
    "size": {
      $size: "$list_ids"
    }
  }
})
```

Witch gives me

```
[
  {
    "_id": "CName",
    "size": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "Alice",
    "size": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "Bob",
    "size": 1
  }
]
```

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0YI5pMNqcex)

Comment: Well, I've tried the same code before. I wanna count the number of documents, but the result of your code is the count of products.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't understand correctly what you were trying to achieve. I've updated my answer